# Elasticsearch filter results excluding by id

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I need to return results that do not include docs with certain ids. Elasticsearch allows us to specify which ids are allowed but I see no way to disallow certain ids. In my case I want to not return things the user has already seen so the list will be different for each user.

Comment: Is there a  specific reason why you need to disallow certain ids. The general approach to those scenarios normally filter the result base on the content of document. You can provide id as a field for that document as well, and exclude those docs with a correct query

Comment: This is not a search app but a recommender. I exclude because the user has purchased the item ids (for example). The doc id can be treated as a field since it IS also stored in a field.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a `bool/must_not` filter containing an `ids` filter with an array of ids you don't want to appear, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         ...                    <--- your other filters go here
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [
              "id1", "id2"      <--- add all the ids you DON'T want in here
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I use this structure for should and must so this will work quite well. This assumes the ids are indexed, right?

Comment: For benefit of others, ids don't have to be indexed explicitly. See:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

Comment: For people using drivers, make sure your list of IDs are strings and not objects like `ObjectId()`